# How to group data based on conditional on datetimes (first record or last record) and count of events over time

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime, filtering, data-wrangling

I have been given two data frames:

**Data frame A:** Has the information of purchases in a clothing store with the variables: name of client, date of purchase, agent and product purchased during a period of time t.

| NAME | PRODUCT | AGENT | DATE_PURCHASE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Karen | M_14 | X_1 | 8-25-20021 18:21:28 |
| Jean | M_78 | X_3 | 8-26-20021 18:11:06 |
| Jean | M_71 | X_4 | 8-26-20021 18:21:01 |
| Jean | M_64 | X_4 | 8-27-20021 20:21:59 |
| Keith | M_57 | X_4 | 8-27-20021 20:21:02 |
| Alba | M_50 | X_1 | 8-28-20021 20:21:03 |
| Alba | M_43 | X_3 | 8-29-20021 20:21:04 |
| Alex | M_36 | X_2 | 8-25-20021 20:21:05 |

**Data frame B**: Has the information of clients who have called the CX SERVICE line of the company during a period of time t and stores the variables name of client, date of call, and type of call.

| NAME | TYPE | DATE_OF_CALL | DATE_PURCHASE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Karen | COMPLAIN | 8-26-20021 18:21:28 | 8-25-20021 18:21:28 |
| Jean | CX_SERVICE | 8-27-20021 18:11:06 | 8-26-20021 18:11:06 |
| Jean | COMPLAIN | 8-28-20021 18:21:01 | 8-26-20021 18:21:01 |
| Jean | CX_SERVICE | 8-29-20021 20:21:59 | 8-27-20021 20:21:59 |
| Keith | CX_SERVICE | 8-29-20021 20:21:02 | 8-27-20021 20:21:02 |
| Alba | COMPLAIN | 8-30-20021 20:21:03 | 8-28-20021 20:21:03 |
| Alex | CX_SERVICE | 8-25-20021 21:21:05 | 8-29-20021 20:21:04 |

I have to build a table in which It will be shown by NAME what was the very **last product purchased** by the customer prior to their **very last call** to the customer service line and it should include the variables: NAME ,LAST_PRODUCT_PURCHASED,    AGENT,  DATE_PURCHASE,  TYPE,   DATE_OF_CALL
that table should look something like this:

***RESULTS***

| NAME | LAST_PRODUCT_PURCHASED | AGENT | DATE_PURCHASE | TYPE | DATE_OF_CALL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Karen | M_14 | X_1 | 8-25-20021 18:21:28 | COMPLAIN | 8-26-20021 18:21:28 |
| Jean | M_64 | X_4 | 8-27-20021 20:21:59 | CX_SERVICE | 8-29-20021 20:21:59 |
| Keith | M_57 | X_4 | 8-27-20021 20:21:02 | CX_SERVICE | 8-29-20021 20:21:02 |
| Alba | M_43 | X_3 | 8-29-20021 20:21:04 | COMPLAIN | 8-30-20021 20:21:03 |
| Alex | M_36 | X_2 | 8-25-20021 20:21:05 | CX_SERVICE | 8-25-20021 21:21:05 |

For example: The second raw shows the desired result as the very last product purchased by Jean was M-78 and her very last call on the line was a TYPE= CX_SERVICE with date 8-29-20021  20:21:59

I have been thinking about doing a group by NAME and DATES or perhaps a join but I can't seen to find a way to deal with the condition of "last" product and "last" date to call on the line

PD: What if we would try to add a column that counts how many time the custumer (NAME) has called prior to their most recent call on the line.

Comment: Please provide data using `dput` which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it, but there is definitely room for improvement:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~NAME, ~PRODUCT, ~AGENT,        ~DATE_PURCHASE,
  "Karen",   "M_14",  "X_1", "8-25-20021 18:21:28",
  "Jean",   "M_78",  "X_3", "8-26-20021 18:11:06",
  "Jean",   "M_71",  "X_4", "8-26-20021 18:21:01",
  "Jean",   "M_64",  "X_4", "8-27-20021 20:21:59",
  "Keith",   "M_57",  "X_4", "8-27-20021 20:21:02",
  "Alba",   "M_50",  "X_1", "8-28-20021 20:21:03",
  "Alba",   "M_43",  "X_3", "8-29-20021 20:21:04",
  "Alex",   "M_36",  "X_2", "8-25-20021 20:21:05"
)

df2 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~NAME,        ~TYPE,         ~DATE_OF_CALL,        ~DATE_PURCHASE,
  "Karen",   "COMPLAIN", "8-26-20021 18:21:28", "8-25-20021 18:21:28",
  "Jean", "CX_SERVICE", "8-27-20021 18:11:06", "8-26-20021 18:11:06",
  "Jean",   "COMPLAIN", "8-28-20021 18:21:01", "8-26-20021 18:21:01",
  "Jean", "CX_SERVICE", "8-29-20021 20:21:59", "8-27-20021 20:21:59",
  "Keith", "CX_SERVICE", "8-29-20021 20:21:02", "8-27-20021 20:21:02",
  "Alba",   "COMPLAIN", "8-30-20021 20:21:03", "8-28-20021 20:21:03",
  "Alex", "CX_SERVICE", "8-25-20021 21:21:05", "8-29-20021 20:21:04"
)

joined_df <- dplyr::full_join(df1, df2, by = "NAME")

solution <- joined_df %>% 
  group_by(NAME) %>% 
  select(-c(DATE_PURCHASE.y)) %>%
  top_n(n = 1, wt = DATE_PURCHASE.x) %>% 
  top_n(n = 1, wt = DATE_OF_CALL) %>% 
  rename("LAST_PRODUCT_PURCHASED" = "PRODUCT",
         "DATE_PURCHASE" = "DATE_PURCHASE.x")

solution
# A tibble: 5 x 6
# Groups:   NAME [5]
#  NAME  LAST_PRODUCT_PURCHASED AGENT DATE_PURCHASE     TYPE       DATE_OF_CALL       
#  <chr> <chr>                  <chr> <chr>               <chr>      <chr>              
#1 Karen M_14                   X_1   8-25-20021 18:21:28 COMPLAIN   8-26-20021 18:21:28
#2 Jean  M_64                   X_4   8-27-20021 20:21:59 CX_SERVICE 8-29-20021 20:21:59
#3 Keith M_57                   X_4   8-27-20021 20:21:02 CX_SERVICE 8-29-20021 20:21:02
#4 Alba  M_43                   X_3   8-29-20021 20:21:04 COMPLAIN   8-30-20021 20:21:03
#5 Alex  M_36                   X_2   8-25-20021 20:21:05 CX_SERVICE 8-25-20021 21:21:05
```

Comment: Jared Thank you for your  time and efforde, I have to praise you for your help I have no words to thank you enough for it. What a talented guy! I would like to kindly ask you if you have the time of course to explain to me what was the thought process behind it as I see that you started about by grouping by NAME which I can undertand but them you use the function top_n  and even change some column names, please let me know where did you coded that the last call should be shown with the last purchsed, or if perhaps you are too bussy can you link some documentation? Thank you so much R_Student